# Configure Log format Cisco ASA firewall

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-ios, cisco-commands, logging

The logs from CISCO ASA fierwall is currently in the following format.

> %ASA-message_class-severity-messageID
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
>    "%ASA-session-6-....."
> ```

I want to remove messsage class from logs

> %ASA-severity-messageID
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
>    "%ASA-6-....."
> ```

I checked in internet and cicso configue help guide, then tried the commands

> ```
>    no logging class session
> ```

But still coming the logs with message class. Please help me

> ```
>    no logging emblem
> ```

Is this work?

Which is the actual command for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you clear the log after applying that command?

Comment: No Ron. Thanks for ur reply. Could you tell me that these steps are correct or not?

Comment: You appear to want to quit logging class 6 messages. http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/cmd_ref/l2.html#wp1770655

Comment: Not really. I want  to remove the  field "message_class" from the logs. I tried the command "no logging class session"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and answers.
I got the correct answer today.
the first message is of **emblem format**
and second one is **default format**.

We can go back to default format by using the following command

> ```
> no logging emblem
> ```

For more details [look **here**](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/command/reference/cmd_ref/l2.html#wpmkr1771268)

Comment: Accept your answer so that it doesn't keep popping up, looking for an answer, forever.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable classes or specific messages, but you can't change the message format.  You will have to do that with an external program.